# Translate not working in Velocity.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity.js

I'm having some trouble animating an element using Velocity.js. My current code does not work (it's meant to translate the element 100 pixels to the right)...

```
$("#example").velocity({ translateX: "100px" });
```

However, interestingly it does work when I change it to the following...

```
$("#example").velocity({ transform: "translateX(100px)" });
```

My example seems to be the same as the code given at http://velocityjs.org/#transforms. Is there any obvious reason why this might be happening?

Here's a JSFiddle to test out my problem, https://jsfiddle.net/zwtoxxfL/2/.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I think this may be different, I am using the jQuery integration of Velocity.js. I've also added a JSFiddle to illustrate my problem more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using version 2.0.2 in your fiddle, which looks to not support that sort of syntax. Velocity hasn't updated their docs - their provided working example on codepen uses version 1.5.0, rather than their newest version.

If you want to use the transform shorthand like that, downgrade to a lower version:

```js
$("div").velocity({ translateX: "100px" });
```

```css
div {
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.5.0/velocity.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Specifically Velocity v2 is still in beta, and I'm not wanting to update the public docs to it until it's out of beta - the new documentation is all in the Velocity Github wiki though :-)